# What is Windows's verfication window process?

Tags: windows

This question is pretty straightforward, what process does "Do you want to allow the following program to make changes to this computer" use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UAC prompt runs as the process `consent.exe`, under the `SYSTEM` user. It displays the prompt on the *Secure Desktop*, also running under `SYSTEM` and completely independent of your normal desktop.

> Executing an image that requests administrative rights causes the Application Information Service (also known as AIS, contained in %SystemRoot%\System32\Appinfo.dll), which runs inside a Service Host process (%SystemRoot%\System32\Svchost .exe), to **launch Consent.exe** (%SystemRoot%\System32\Consent.exe). Consent captures a bitmap of the screen, applies a fade effect to it, switches to a desktop that’s only accessible to the Local System account, paints the bitmap as the background, and displays an elevation dialog box that contains information about the executable.

-- Mark Russinovich, [Security: Inside Windows Vista User Account Control](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2007.06.uac.aspx)

---

See also:

<sup>UAC hasn't changed much between Windows versions, though some articles are targeted towards specific versions. Most of what is mentioned in earlier articles is still relevant and correct on the latest Windows.</sup>

- [Security: Inside Windows Vista User Account Control](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2007.06.uac.aspx) (TechNet, Mark Russinovich)
- [How does consent.exe know what to display?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85844/how-does-consent-exe-know-what-to-display) (Stack Exchange)
- [How does the Windows “Secure Desktop” mode work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3759/how-does-the-windows-secure-desktop-mode-work) (Stack Exchange)
- [UAC Processes and Interactions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835561(v=ws.10).aspx) (TechNet documentation, Windows 7)
- [How User Account Control Works](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574202(v=ws.11).aspx) (TechNet documentation, Windows 8)
- [How User Account Control works](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/access-protection/user-account-control/how-user-account-control-works) (TechNet documentation, Windows 10)